# Code Coverage Varies when i block a line in test class

Tags: unit-test

Can any one help me out .Code coverage varies when i block a line.In the test class if i block

```
`AvoidRecursiveCloning.cloneCreated = false;`
```

this line the code coverage displayed is 5% and if i uncomment it it shows as 87%.But when i check in production the code coverage displayed is 67% even when the line is commented.Why is this variations in code coverage.Any help very much appreciated.

**Test Class :**

```
@isTest
public class TestCreateSubscriptionOpptyClone1 
{
    static testMethod void test1()
    {
        Account acc1 = new Account(Name='Testing SubscriptionClone', BillingStreet='Banjara hills', BillingCity='Hyd', BillingState='TS',
                                    BillingPostalCode = '500084', BillingCountry = 'India', Phone = '100', Industry = 'Banking',
                                    Type = 'Paid', Customer_Type__c = 'Customer', Customer_List__c = true,PPAS__c = false,
                                    PPCD__c = false,PPSP__c = false, PGSQL__c = false,PPAS_Developer_Sub__c = false,      
                                    PPSP_Developer_Sub__c = false, PGSQL_Developer_Sub__c = false,RDBA__c = false,  
                                    Services__c = false,Training__c = false,SteelEye__c = false,Jump_Start_Subscription__c = false    );  
        insert acc1 ;


        contact cc = new contact(FirstName ='Test Contact Subscription', LastName ='Opptyclone', Role__c='Subscription Administrator',AccountId=acc1.Id);
        insert cc;

        Opportunity opty = new Opportunity(Name = 'Test SubscriptionOppty', StageName ='Proposal/Price Quote', Probability =60, 
                                            CloseDate = System.Today(), Type = 'Existing Customer', Assigned_Sales_Engineer__c = null, 
                                            Update_Complete__c = true, Partner__c = 'None', Anchor__c='Non Anchor', AccountId = acc1.Id,
                                            Payment_Type__c = 'Order Form', LeadSource = 'Subscription Renewal');
        insert opty;




        list<OpportunityContactRole> opptyConRolelist1 =  new list<OpportunityContactRole>{
            new OpportunityContactRole(ContactId = cc.Id, OpportunityId = opty.Id, IsPrimary = false, Role = 'Subscription Administrator')
        };   
        insert opptyConRolelist1;

        product2 p2 = new product2(Name ='Postgres Plus Enterprise Edition Unicores', Product_Name1__C='Product - Subscription', Product_Group__c='PPAS',
                                    IsActive = true, Description='Postgres Plus Enterprise Edition Unicores', ARR_Impact1__c = 'Yes');
        insert p2;

        PricebookEntry pbey = new PricebookEntry(Product2ID=p2.id, Pricebook2ID= test.getStandardPricebookId(), UnitPrice=50, isActive=true);
        insert pbey;

        Opportunitylineitem ooli = new Opportunitylineitem(OpportunityId = opty.Id, PricebookEntryId = pbey.Id, Quantity =4, 
                                    Start_Date__c = System.today(), End_Date__c =  System.today() + 100, Type_of_Contract__c='None',
                                    Term__c =12, Type_Of_Product__c='Single Year Subscription', Type_of_ARR__c= 'New Addition ARR',
                                    TotalPrice=1750, No_ARR__c = false, In_Year_Billing__c = 10);
        insert ooli;

        Opportunitylineitem ooli1 = new Opportunitylineitem(OpportunityId = opty.Id, PricebookEntryId = pbey.Id, Quantity =4, 
                                    Start_Date__c = System.today(), End_Date__c =  System.today() + 100, Type_of_Contract__c='None',
                                    Term__c =12, Type_Of_Product__c='Single Year Subscription', Type_of_ARR__c= 'New Addition ARR',
                                    TotalPrice=1750, No_ARR__c = false, In_Year_Billing__c = 10, Parent_Opportunity_Product_Id__c=ooli.Id);
        insert ooli1;

         Contract contr = new Contract(CurrencyIsoCode='USD', Annual_Contract_Value__c =5000, Type_Of_Product__c='Single Year Subscription',
                                        Notes__c='Contract is getting created', Opportunity_Product_Id__c= ooli.Id, Contracts_In_Year_Billing__c=1500,
                                        AccountId=acc1.Id);
        insert contr;

        acc1.PPCD__c = true;
        opty.StageName = 'Closed Won';
       // AvoidRecursiveCloning.cloneCreated = false;
        Test.startTest();
         update acc1;
        update opty;

        opty.StageName = 'Closed Lost';
       // AvoidRecursiveCloning.cloneCreated = false;
        update opty;

        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code your testing?

Comment: @EricSSH,@crmprogdev:Thanks for your response.The Source code is around 400+ lines.Where im unable to post .ANy suggestion please.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason for the discrepancy has to do with transaction context and trigger recursive control static variables

In PROD, when you insert Accounts, Opportunities, etc, each insert is one (1) transaction and all static variables are reset between transactions.

But in a testmethod, the entire testmethod is one transaction and static variables retain their values across the whole testmethod. So, if you are doing any kind of recursive trigger control in the triggers for Account or Opportunity, those static variables are set when you mock the records and thus, when you come around to ...

```
Test.startTest();
     update acc1;
     update opty;

    opty.StageName = 'Closed Lost';
    // AvoidRecursiveCloning.cloneCreated = false;
    update opty;

Test.stopTest();
```

...the DML on Account and Opportunity run into your trigger recursive control guards and do nothing

As an aside, I presume you are doing asserts after `Test.stoptest()` to verify code accuracy, not just code coverage.

To work around this, what I do is use test factories to mock my Sobjects and the factories reset the trigger recursion guards before returning the sobjects

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the source code your test class is running on, the fact you're only testing 1 record at a time is very likely the reason for the discrepancy. You probably need the cloned records in order to create more records for testing. If you created lists of records to test with, you'd be less likely to see these kinds of issues, but again, it's impossible to say without seeing your source code the test class is for.